# Scroll conflict with html Object

Tags: javascript, html, object, scroll

My website has some issues, when i scroll down and i reach the halfway, the scroll system begins to blink and it looks like the site is jammed.

site: http://www.alessandrapinto.it/

I noticed that this kind of problem occours when i find an html oblject that i've used in my website, more specifically:

```
<object type="text/html" data="evenom/index.php"></object>
```

Why does this problem occour? Can it be solved? Could it be a conflict? I'm not able to find a solution

Comment: What browser specifically?

Comment: All browser, but on chrome less

Comment: Hmm... out of my head... so ***probably*** since you use that parallax scrolling that does some pretty heavy stuff with the scrollbar... probably it misses (or messes) calculating the element height where you call your `<object>`. Have you tried to simply include that slider without the use of `<object>`?

Comment: Also, what about using the good old `<iframe>` instead of `<object>`? Even than, I really see no good reason for including that slider that way...

Comment: In any case, I think that disabling that funny smooth-scroll (only the part related to smooth scrolling, not the whole parallax stuff) script you'll get the best results. Personally that scroll script forces me to do extra scrolls cause it actually scrolls the page really slow (Chrome, Edge)... Sorry for not being much of help.